# Can you block sending an SMS from Twilio to a specific number? And easily lift the block afterwards?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I've been trawling through the support docs but they are mostly about blocking incoming SMS.  I'm looking for a way to block sending SMS, within an existing flow, to specific numbers at various times and then be able to lift that block again, relatively easily.

Some of the users of our system have a very specific use case where they would be inundated with SMS and I'm wondering if this might be a workaround.

Comment: Twillio has a opt out system that you can enable where stop or start type of responses opt numbers in and out so they will be blocked but from what your describing and based on your needs it seems that you need to set up some type of system yourself of the numbers you want to use and not use at any particular time

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t a way to block inbound SMS. You can remove the webhook but the inbound SMS are lost. There is an API to provision webhooks on numbers.

For outbound, you need to code the logic on your side.

Answer (score 0):

I set up Google Sheets to sent SMS by list, using this guide:
https://techandeco.medium.com/send-sms-event-updates-or-discount-codes-using-twilio-from-a-google-sheet-fd1ebd24c4e

You could add some kind of "Flag" column and modify the code to skip the numbers that are not "flagged".